# if...elseif error while entering values again and again

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

While in this program I have to enter the temperature again and again in a loop. While I enter the temperature once it shows the correct display, but when I enter the temperature again the program terminates itself.

The code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckTemperature
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        final double TEMPERATURE = 102.5;
        double thermostat;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the substance's temperature: ");
        thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if(thermostat > TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.print("The temperature is too high. ");
            System.out.print("Turn down the thermostat. ");
            System.out.println("Wait for 5 minutes and check the thermostat again. "); 
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        else if(thermostat < TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.println("The temperature is low.");
            System.out.println("Turn up the thermostat.");
            System.out.println("Check for 5 minutes and check again.");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        else if(thermostat == TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.println("The temperature is acceptable. Check again in 15 minutes.");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the correct temperature value ");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _...again and again in a loop_. Your code doesn't have any loop.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your are not in a loop. you ask the temperature once at the top.
Then once in a if, then it's end.

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    final double TEMPERATURE = 102.5;
    double thermostat;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the substance's temperature: ");
        thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if(thermostat > TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.print("The temperature is too high. ");
            System.out.print("Turn down the thermostat. ");
            System.out.println("Wait for 5 minutes and check the thermostat again. ");
        }
        else if(thermostat < TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.println("The temperature is low.");
            System.out.println("Turn up the thermostat.");
            System.out.println("Check for 5 minutes and check again.");
        }

        else if(thermostat == TEMPERATURE) {

            System.out.println("The temperature is acceptable. Check again in 15 minutes.");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Enter the correct temperature value ");
        }
    }
}
```

Be carefull, the while will never stop, but you can change the condition as you wish.

Comment: Why `while (1 == 1)` and not `while (true)` ?

Comment: The last `else` is redundant, there is no way the `thermostat` can neither be less, equal nor greater than the constant.

Comment: @Clashsoft well, you can input `NaN` (and it will be correctly parsed), and `NaN` is not greater/less/equal than/to anything, even itself, so then you'll end up in the last `else` block.

Comment: @Roman, because i was in a hurry. I answered fast. You can edit if you want, or i'll do tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Roman please suggest some corrections in this: I used the line as and it gives the error as double cannot be dereferenced : value=keyboard.nextDouble();
if(keyboard.equals("0"))

Answer (score 4):

if you want to get temperature again and again you have to use a loop.

```
while(true){
    if(thermostat > TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.print("The temperature is too high. ");
            System.out.print("Turn down the thermostat. ");
            System.out.println("Wait for 5 minutes and check the thermostat again. "); 
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();

        }
        else if(thermostat < TEMPERATURE)
        {
            System.out.println("The temperature is low.");
            System.out.println("Turn up the thermostat.");
            System.out.println("Check for 5 minutes and check again.");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();

        }

        else if(thermostat == TEMPERATURE) {

            System.out.println("The temperature is acceptable. Check again in 15 minutes.");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Enter the correct temperature value ");
            System.out.println("Enter the thermostat here: ");
            thermostat = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not built to 'repeat' any task AKA iterate. Add a loop to your code to make it repeat the action as desired.

Here we use the `while (1==1)` to create an infinite loop. Also, we add an exit criteria in checking for input == "X", which triggers a `System.exit` from the loop. This helps to maintain a graceful exit from the application, without having to force close.

```
    final double TEMPERATURE = 102.5;
    double thermostat;
    while(true){
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter the substance's temperature or press X to exit: ");
           String input = keyboard.next();
           if(input.equals("X")){
              System.exit(0);
           } else{
              thermostat = Double.parseDouble(input);   
              if(thermostat > TEMPERATURE) {
                    System.out.print("The temperature is too high. ");
                    System.out.print("Turn down the thermostat. ");
                    System.out.println("Wait for 5 minutes and check the thermostat again. "); 
                } else if(thermostat < TEMPERATURE) {
                    System.out.println("The temperature is low.");
                    System.out.println("Turn up the thermostat.");
                    System.out.println("Check for 5 minutes and check again.");
                } else if(thermostat == TEMPERATURE) {
                    System.out.println("The temperature is acceptable. Check again in 15 minutes.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter the correct temperature value ");
                }
           }
    }
```

Comment: (keyboard.nextString().equals("X") is returning cannot find symol error. I used the 0 key to exit because i was reading a double value. error is:  CheckTemperature.java:13: error: double cannot be dereferenced
                        if(keyboard.nextDouble().equals("0"))
                                                ^
1 error

Comment: Oops.. Sorry. My Bad. It should be `keyboard.next()`. Fixed it and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Murtaza,You can just use a loop or can use any recursive method and call it in your main method.and the error that you are talking about DOUBLE CANNOT BE DEREFERENCED is due to the fact that there is no such method like equals() in Scanner class.besides,you should not compare an int value with a double type variable.And again,to compare it inside an if-else block,you should use equals() method present in Double,the wrapper class against passing an object as its parameter.